# Condition number on perturbations cannot cancel $||x||$ in inequality.

Tags: perturbation-theory, matrix-norms, condition-number

Theorem
Let $A$ be a square matrix, then
$$\lim_{k \to \infty } A_{k} =0 \rightarrow \rho(A)<1$$
Moreover, the geometric series case $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_{k}$ is convergent iff  $\rho(A) < 1$. In such a

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_{k} = (I - A)^{-1}.$$
As a result, if $rho(A) < 1$ the matrix $I - A$ is invertible and the following
inequalities hold
$$\frac{1}{1+||A||} \leq ||(I-A)^{-1}|| \leq \frac{1}{1 - ||A||}$$

where $||\cdot||$ is an induced matrix norm such that $||A|| < $1.

From $$(A + \delta A)(x+ \delta x) = b + \delta b$$ it follows that $$(I+A^{-1}\delta A)(x+ \delta x)= x+A^{-1}\delta b.$$
Moreover since $\gamma \mu(A) < 1$ and $||\delta A|| \leq \gamma ||A||$ it turns out that $I-A^{-1}\delta A$ is non singular.
Taking the inverse of such a matrix and passing to the norms we get $$||x+ \delta x || \leq ||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)^{-1}|| (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||)$$.

From theorem then it follows that:
$$||x+ \delta x || \leq  \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||) $$

Substituting $||b|| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||x||$ then i obtain:

\begin{align*}
    ||x+ \delta x || \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\gamma ||A||)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||A|| \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-\gamma \mu(A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-\gamma \mu(A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{1-\gamma \mu(A)}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||}{1-\gamma \mu(A)} 
\end{align*}

But the true inequality is :

$$\frac{||x+ \delta x ||}{||x||} \leq  \frac{1 + \gamma \mu(A) }{1-\gamma \mu(A)}$$

and this $||x||$ cannot avoid it.What I am doing wrong?Any help?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
    ||x+ \delta x || \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\delta A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||b||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-A^{-1}\gamma ||A||)||}  (||x|| + \gamma||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||A|| \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-\gamma \mu(A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{||(I-\gamma \mu(A)||}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{1}{1-\gamma \mu(A)}  (||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||) \\
    \leq & \frac{||x|| + \gamma \mu(A) \cdot ||x||}{1-\gamma \mu(A)}  \\
     \leq &\frac{||x||(1 + \gamma \mu(A)) }{1-\gamma \mu(A)} \\
   \frac{||x+ \delta x ||}{||x||}\leq &\frac{1 + \gamma \mu(A) }{1-\gamma \mu(A)}
\end{align*}